# Angular MatDialog 'bootstrap' not showing right or missing

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-components, angular-bootstrap

I am using Angular MatDialog. I have issue with it, not showing right and with the styles, backdrop, etc..
I have

```
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

and also in app.module:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

Is my project missing some dependencies ?
I have @angular/material 9.1.3, @angular/animations 9.1.3 already in my package.json

[image: Mat dialog. Works but styles are not there]

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem, I was not setting a default angular material theme in my styles.scss file such as:

@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

or a custom theme as described here:
https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-4-include-a-theme

Answer (score 0):

from [angular material theming guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme):

If you're using Angular CLI, this is as simple as including one line in your styles.css file:

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Alternatively, you can just reference the file directly. This would look something like:

```html
<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```